# Accessing odoo html/css/js editor

Tags: html, odoo, editor

Using Odoo 15.0

I went to customize -> html/css/js editor and added a link to the header in html

[image]

This link broke the js on the website including the action buttons (edit, new ..) and html/css/js editor as well

now I want to access the editor so I can remove the link from html

Is there any way to access it other than the dropdown button?

Answer (score 1):

This question is resolved by

- Going to settings
- General settings -> Developer Tools (section) -> activate the developer mode
- Inside settings a new link will be added to the toolbar called 'Technical'
- In Technical dropdown choose views
- From views filter by QWeb (here where all website views are: pages, header, navbar, footer ..etc)
- Remove the buggy code from the view you edited or edit the code you need in there